# How to create thumbnails with hover display on plain HTML page?

Tags: html, thumbnails

I have some large .png (.jpg, ...) files that require pretty much a full screen to see.  How do I create thumbnails on a standard HTML page?  Is there some kind of size scaling control in the  tag that I've somehow missed?

Can I get the large image to display when the mouse hovers over such a thumbnail?
(JavaScript and CSS are OK for either answer).

EDIT: Since target browsers may be showing at different size resolutions, how do I keep the thumbnail proportionally scaled to the displayed size of the web page/text?

Comment: I know this has been answered well, but just to say that you can specify image height and width in the img tag. So you could display the large image at a small size initially, but it's not very good for the user's bandwidth.

Comment: So the image tag sends the entire .png file, and the remote browser does the scaling?  I guess that makes sense in terms of simple implementation of browsers.   That's probably not gonna be good, since we're likely to have this on many of our pages.   So I probably need a real thumbnail to keep it small?  Is there a standard way to make thumbnails, or is it just find your favorite picture editor and tell it scale what you have?  What happens if the target browser is showing different size resolutions?

Comment: Yes, yes and find your favourite editor. I don't quite understand the last question, but browsers should do what you say in terms of using the size you specify in pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique really amounts to smoke and mirrors, since both images are directly coded on the page. However, the larger image is made invisible through CSS and only becomes visible when the visitor hovers over the link. Clicking the link opens the full-size image in the new page. The image above is coded as:

```
<div id="links" align="center">
  <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(../thumbs/294.jpg)">
    <a href="../images/nebulan90.jpg" target="_blank">
    Nebula N90<img src="../images/nebulan90-s.jpg" alt="Nebula N90" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Images that are linked within the  division are automatically hidden through CSS:

```
#links a img {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

Since all images are automatically hidden, it is necessary to display the thumbnail as a background image outside of the actual link. In order for the link to work over the image and display the text below the image (instead of over it), it is necessary to include this code:

```
#links a {
  display:block;
  padding-top: 110px;
}
```

The larger image is revealed above the link when the cursor is hovered over it:

```
#links a:hover img {
  position: relative;
  top: -260px;
  left: -90px;
  height: 240px;
  width: 320px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #0ff;
}
```

Comment: Following on from my comment above. Do you know if the large image is loaded by the browser before the hovering happens?